# DBA.SE Birthday Celebration?

Tags: discussion

Did you know DBA’s anniversary of its graduation is coming up on **16 August**? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) or at the [**Unix & Linux Birthday Bash**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention through your moderator team! We're really interested in community-lead initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “Let's go!”

Comment: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/762 ?

Comment: Happy Birthday DBA.SE!  Many happy returns! :P

Answer (score 6):

For the London crowd, may I suggest drinkies at a location with wifi and something solid enough to kensington lock a laptop to?

For our friends from across the ditch and down under I suspect the geographical distribution might hinder similar efforts elsewhere , but one can try.

May I suggest we award a prize for 'top gun' to @gbn in the form of a return ticket to London and a substantial bar tab ...

**EDIT:** So far we have a plan B that involves using Jack's phone, which has a mobile wifi hotspot feature.  Won't have the bandwidth for a video conference but we could have an event on the heap for it.

Comment: Is there anything like a Budapest crowd here?  It would be nice to adapt this highly original and brilliant idea.

Comment: I don't know. By coincidence, myself, JackDouglas and @MarkStoreySmith live fairly close to each other.  With wifi and skype one could possibly do a distributed drinking session.

Comment: Sounds like a good use of a [broadcast hangout](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/google-hangouts-on-air-broadcast-your.html) to me. :D

Comment: @Aarthi - want to join us?

Comment: In London? Of course. :P

Comment: @Aarthi - via a broadcast hangout ;)

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells - Ping me with details if this happens.  I'd like to join.

Comment: @NickChammas - at least you'll have decent wifi in Korea :)

Comment: @Nick Korea?!? *Searches for "Korea" in The Heap* - ahhh, that's what you are up to. Having fun I hope?

Comment: @JackDouglas - He'll be really good at starcraft when he gets back.

Comment: @JackDouglas - So far so good. I've been blessed with good co-coworkers and welcoming locals.  CoTW, so you've heard. :) Man, they have "e-sports" channels here, some of which just show StarCraft matches with Korean commentary all day.

Comment: What about those of us who don't drink? Or don't get online that often? :(

Comment: @ChrisAldrich - drinking isn't strictly necessary.  Not sure how one can do a distributed meetup without going online though :)

Comment: @ChrisAldrich I be watching COTW drink rather than doing any myself - much more fun ;-)

Comment: @JackDouglas - lol :)